# WordPress is_user_logged_in()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to see if the user is logged in on WordPress by using the intended function: `is_user_logged_in()`.

Weird is, when I log out, it still returns true. What am I doing wrong?

```
function test() {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
      ...
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'test' );
```

Comment: Can you do a var_dump of that function? i.e: `var_dump(is_user_logged_in());`

Comment: @Hatef That gives me this: `bool(true)`

Comment: seems like a cookie issue! Can you try in cognito mode and see if it behaves the same?

Comment: After deleting a cookie called 'logged_in' with a bunch of random chars, it worked. WordPress should [delete auth cookies when logging out](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_auth_cookie), how can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you caching the page?

Comment: @NathanDawson No, there are no caching plugins enabled, and WordPress doesn't cache by default, I think.

Comment: I might have found the issue - give me a moment

Comment: So it is a cookie issue! Can you try this in the logout process? `<?php wp_clear_auth_cookie(); ?>`

Comment: Could you be interfering with the logout process? If there's an error it's possible it's preventing the cookies from being cleared correctly.

Comment: @NathanDawson Correct! As written [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_auth_cookie) this function can easily be replaced by plugins.

Comment: Issue resolved - the problem was a debug plugin creating the cookie, that plugin creates the cookie so I don't auto-logout. When logged in, you still can visit `wp-login.php`. I've added a redirect on the login page using `is_user_logged_in` and `$pagenow == 'wp-login.php'` which will redirect to `admin_url()` when the user is logged in. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try your code by this way.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{
    $logged = TRUE
} 
else 
{
    echo 'false';
    $logged = FALSE
}
```

Then just add this condition on any content :

```
if($logged) 
{
    echo 'Logged in';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'not logged in'; 
}
```

Comment: Have you inspect your cookies? Are any being set?